# passing a huge string parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

i have a stored procedure that takes 2 parameters: ID and Date.
when i pass a big text to the ID parameter, only part of the text is taken into consideration. as if the text is cut at a certain place. i figured this because when i execute the stored procedure as following:

```
 exec proc '1,2,3,4', '20100101'
```

everthing works find
but when i use a big string instead of the 1st argument only part of the string is cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the first parameter of your stored procedure has limited size. In Management Studio locate the procedure, right click, choose **Modify** or **Script->Alter To..** Look for the declaration of the first parameter and change it to `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`.

Answer (score 0):

See the definition of the stored procedure - it has defined parameters it expects (right click in SqlServer Management studio - click "Modify")

See how much is defined for the first argument and alter according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change the Data type of this string, try to use `varchar(Max)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestXMLIN 
( 
@XMLDOC AS TEXT 
) 
AS 
DECLARE @xmlHandle INT 

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlHandle OUTPUT, @xmlDoc 

SELECT * 
FROM OPENXML (@xmlHandle, '/P/C', 2) WITH 
( 
MajorCode VARCHAR(10) './MJ', 
MinorCode VARCHAR(10) './MI' 
) 
)OXML 
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @xmlHandle
```